# Contatenating strings using sprintf

Tags: string, matlab, printf

I wonder why the following code does not work?

```
function out = test(str1, str2)
    aux = sprintf(str1, str2);
end
```

Somehow MATLAB does not like how I supply the argument `str1`, which is entered by the user, to the function `sprintf`.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

Read the documentation on [`sprintf`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html) in MATLAB. It's rather clear what's wrong: the first argument in your case. MATLAB's `sprintf` requires a format spec, so unless the first argument is a format specification, rather than say `'hello'` matching the second string, this won't work. You'll probably want something along the lines of `sprintf('%s %s', str1, str2)` or `sprintf([str1 ' ' str2])`, i.e. explicitly concatenating the strings into one literal text string first.

Your current function will work if you call it as `test('%s', 'hello')` by the way, or even `test('%f %f', [pi 5])`. So you might want to use input verification to make sure you're only inputting strings.